# Unable to unpickle custom exception taking kwargs as argument

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import pickle


class CustomEx(Exception):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.a = kwargs.get('a')
        assert self.a, "a must present"


s = pickle.dumps(CustomEx(a='a'))
pickle.loads(str(s)) # this fails
```

I'm using python version 2.7.13. Please advise how can I make it work. It fails with following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/app/tmp/pickle_user_purchase_required.py", line 10, in <module>
    pickle.loads(str(s))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1388, in loads
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1139, in load_reduce
    value = func(*args)
  File "/Users/app/tmp/pickle_user_purchase_required.py", line 6, in __init__
    assert self.a, "a must present"
AssertionError: a must present
```

Comment: Is there an error? What is not working? Show the current output/behavior and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: I was unable to answer properly, but seems that pickle is not able to operate properly when constructor is using keyword/positional arguments

Comment: I don't undestand what do you want to do, but in python 2 you have 2 pickle, and I used pickle to write or read a data from a file, and cPickle to read or write a data in the script... what do you want to do?